# use session_start () on pages other than the login page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Can you help me with this question?

I need to capture the value of the existing session, however, it would be on another page that is not the login page. Is it okay to use session_start () on this page as well? My fear is that other users' data will intersect.

I have already tried to pass the session value through an input hidden contained in a form (this form is part of the project), but this is **vulnerable**, since this value can be changed when inspecting the page.
In this project, I'm also using jQuery, because I give options to add buttons. So, when the user clicks to publish, I use serialize () in the form id and send it to another page to process the data through the post method.

```
<div id="corpo">
<span id="msg"></span>
<div id="corpo-form">
    <h1>Meu roteiro</h1>
    <form id="add-pub" method="POST" autocomplete="off">

        <div class="inputBox" id="titulo-rot"> <!-- caixa de entrada -->
            <input type="text" name="titulo" required="" placeholder="Insira um nome para o seu roteiro aqui e o valor ao lado!">
            <input type="number" name="valor" required="" min="0" max="100000" value ="0">
        </div>
        <div id="formulario">
            <div class="inputBox"> <!-- caixa de entrada -->
                <input  type="text" name="descricao[]" required="" placeholder="Digite aqui!">
                <button type="button" id="add-campo"> + </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
            //echo "<input type='hidden' name='hid' value='" . hidden($_SESSION['id_usuarios']) . "'>";
        ?>
        <input type="button" name="PubRot" id="PubRot" value="PUBLICAR">
    </form>
</div>
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var cont = 1;
    $( "#add-campo" ).click(function() {
        cont++;
        $( '<div class="inputBox" id="campo'+cont+'"> <input type="text" name="descricao[]" required="" placeholder="Digite aqui!"> <button type="button" id="'+cont+'" class="btn-apagar"> - </button> </div>' ).appendTo( "#formulario" );
    });

    $( "form" ).on( "click", ".btn-apagar", function() {
        var button_id = $( this ).attr("id");

        $( '#campo' +button_id+'' ).remove();
    });

    $("#PubRot").click(function(){
        var dados = $("#add-pub").serialize();
        $.post("insert_rot.php", dados, function(retorna){

            //$("#msg").slideDown('slow').html(retorna);

            $('#add-pub')[0].reset();

            //retirarMsg();
        })
    });
});
```

Would it be possible to pass on the value of the session without it being visible or easily manipulated?

I just didn't use session_start () for fear of conflict with other logged in users. If there is no conflict, could i use it smoothly?

If you can help me, I will be very grateful! :)

Comment: If you use session_start on one page you should use it on ALL PAGES

Comment: If the session is started on page1, then `session_start()` on page2 will pick up the previously started/created session. That is basically the whole point of a session

Comment: If in doubt on ANYTHING PHP Related, if all else fails [Read the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: I am using it in a header.php and including that header on the other pages. But in this case, "insert_rot.php" handles the data coming from the form. if I include the header in "insert_rot.php" it will add things that I don't want, because I only want the session value

Comment: In that case, separate out your includes so you can do more granular includes in your page. That has nothing specifically to do with use of sessions, it's just the logical organisation of your application. P.S. `My fear is that other users' data will intersect`...how do you imagine that would happen? The session is unique to the browser connection (it's done using cookies). Unless someone can steal the session ID from the browser cookie, then you should not have any fear. Please make sure you understand the basics of sessions before you actually try to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session_start() as needed. PHP gives a different session ID to every client, you don't need to worry about mixing sessions unless someone copies the session ID of another person which is another topic. You can use session_start anywhere needed.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the `if condition`

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

you can read more information here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php